# Capacitor in Network of Resistors

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Here is the circuit
[image]

I know that Vc(t)=Vs(1-e^(-t/RC)) but I'm not sure if Vs in this case refers to the 50V or the voltage across the capacitor.  If it is the voltage across the capacitor how would I solve it?  What would be the resistance of the capacitor?  I was told that capacitors act as short circuit initially so would I assume it's resistance is 0?  I couldn't find anything that showed how to solve RC circuits this complex, they were always just a single resistor and capacitor.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to determine equivalent source R and Vs from the 3 resistors and one of them has no effect on Vs

Comment: Ok, that sounds a bit like Thevenin theorem, so would I just remove the capacitor and calculate the Veq and Req at those points? So Vs would be 25V and R would be 10||(20+10)=7.5

Comment: No the battery has 0 R and 20 in shunt is not in series so ... try again

Comment: Right, so R should be 10||10 = 5 because the battery is replaced with a short.  Thanks for the help.